# Is it possible make a CSS rule that combines two or more other CSS rules?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For instance:

```
.strong {
        font-weight: bold;
}
.italicized {
        font-style: italic;
}
.strong_and_italicized {
        .strong;
        .italicized;
}
```

I ask because I'm working on some jquery that is manipulating some DOM objects that have been assigned multiple different classes from the jquery ui theme css file. It seems to me it would be much easier to combine the multiple classes into one class and then I could just refer to that class in the javascript code when trying to select the DOM object.

Comment: AFAIK you cant. I remember a blog post years ago complaining how css doesnt have something as basic as const values. There are tools to generate css. If i remembered any i would write it as an answer but i cant sorry. -edit- ok answers below list them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to combine CSS classes into one like that, that I know of, is to use a CSS pre-processor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

If you don't want to use that, I'm afraid you have to assign both classes separately.

Answer (score 4):

With pure CSS there's no way of combining two other existing rules.

If you need to combine two css rules, just use both classes on the element:

```
.foo {
  color: #F00;
}
.bar {
  font-size: 10px;
}

<div class="foo bar"></div>
```

With CSS you *can* chain selectors:

```
.foo.bar {
  color: #0F0;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

And jQuery will select elements with chained classes too:

```
$('.foo.bar').do(stuff);
```

---

Additionally, don't ***ever*** write classes that imply style. It's not semantic and makes for a harder time when you want to reuse your HTML but change your css.

Something like:

```
.italicized {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

wont make sense, whereas:

```
.title {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

has no implication for styling.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly that with [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/). It even uses the syntax in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding a comma to each of the CSS rule inorder to group them