# Use only one of properties of css class in other css class

Tags: css

I have a problem, I need to use one property of a css class in other css class.

> .class_a {margin:10px; width: 360px; float: left; color:#ffffff; ...etc...}
>
> .class_b { .class_a of margin }

use in class_b only margin of class_a

thanks!

Comment: Not possible in pure CSS. CSS preprocessors like LESS can do this.

Comment: How come you want to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible make a CSS rule that combines two or more other CSS rules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114861/is-it-possible-make-a-css-rule-that-combines-two-or-more-other-css-rules)

Comment: Can you move the declaration of the margin to a new class, then add that class to the HTML elements which receive `class_a`?

Comment: I want to use jquery ui themes, but just colors and bg-s.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using traditional CSS, you need to use dynamic approach like `LESS` or `SASS`

[LESS Reference](http://lesscss.org/)

[SASS Reference](http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your quickest option here might be to find the styles you want with firebug or chrome developer tools and add them to your stylesheet.